# Unable to write in user setting VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio, settings, visual-studio-code

I think I accidentally messed up some of the built-in code for my user setting page. When I tried changing the word wrap or activate auto-complete HTML, the message "unable to write in user setting" showed up, which led me to this user setting page. But I'm not sure how to fix it
[vs code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUWJF.png)

Comment: Delete the second `"auto-close-tag......"` line.  You have two of them, keep the one with the array `[` opener.

Comment: @Mark it works, thank you so much!